# java remove certain special characters

Tags: java, regex

Sorry, it might be duplicated post but i'm not really understand how this regex works. I had referred others post yet still confuse. I trying to remove certain special characters when i import file from excel. Any help would be appreciated.

below are the example the data i get from excel:

```
String test = "HELLO~I!Am@B#C(D)an`d|OPQ/HMM\YES^123,.&*$" 
test = test.replaceAll("[^-A-Za-z0-9", " ");  // not completed regex
```

i have no idea how to write a full regex to replace only these characters like ` ^ \ / | * 
       to empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put `^` at the start of char class, since it's a special class in regex called negated character class.

```
string.replaceAll("[/\\\\|*^`]", "");
```

In java regex, you need to use four backslashes to match a literal backslash character.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/E9RXFQ)

If you want to remove `[`, `]` also, you need to include `\\[`, `\\]` inside the character class.

```
string.replaceAll("[/\\\\|*^`\\[\\]]", "");
```

Comment: Hi @Avinah Raj may i know how to remove this two ? [ and ] symbol ?